# vb.net windows service - delete file but in use by another process

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have a windows service that transmits files to a web service.  If its successful, it tries to remove all document associated with this filing.

This was a very rare occurance on the windows 2003 server, but last night moved it to a Windows 2012 R2 server (quad core).  Now its happening more frequently.

Here is the typical error.

> The process cannot access the file 'c:\abc\123456.txt' because it is being used by another process.

Any suggestions on how to change this code below. I have thought about making the service sleep a second before the delete, but not sure if that's really the best solution either.

```
If isReadyToDelete Then
    ' Delete all of the filing's documents from disk.
    For Each doc In Filing.documents

        Try
            File.Delete(String.Format("{0}\{1}_{2}.{3}", My.Settings.FilingDirectory, Filing.filing.ID, doc.ID, My.Settings.FileExtension))

        Catch ex As Exception

            ErrorHandler.LogError(ex, _
            String.Format("Unable to delete {0}\{1}_{2}.{3}", My.Settings.FilingDirectory, Filing.filing.ID, doc.ID, My.Settings.FileExtension), _
            ErrorSeverityLevels.Medium, _
            MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().ReflectedType.FullName, MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name)

        End Try
    Next
End If
```

Comment: More interesting would be the code that transfers the file to the web service. The error says the file is still opened. Nothing **you** can do about it. Maybe in your code you're forgetting to close it? Or some anti-virus software is scanning it?

Comment: The process the transfers the files are DLLs provided to us by that agency.  Whats weird is this code would happen once or twice a month.  I have had 20 since 630am.  Also, we send about 3000 documents a day through this process.

Comment: If file is in read state by any process, then obviously windows doesn't allow to read it unless file is not in use. So if you are getting this error then may be you can use any other drive than `C` where your server is installed. I'm not very confident whether this will help. If this doesn't then you may write a very small utility to cleanup file from disk (another window service which will execute at every half an hour or so and will delete file one by one)

Comment: I had something similar once. I had to rename the file, then have a process that periodically tries to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

When I last wrote code like this it turned out to be the anti virus causing trouble but it can also be the indexing service.

As a workaround I ended up writing code that repeatedly tried to do the deletes. I stored the list of files that I had failed to delete in a database so when I got restarted etc I retried the deletes (I think I tried 10 times with escalating timeouts i.e. 10,30 seconds followed by multiple minutes)

To figure "What" is causing the problem you can use sysinternals ProcMon to look for CreateFile and if I remember correctly you can also put a filter on so you only see the path your're interested in.

Comment: We Excluded the directory of the files from the Anti-Virus and I added a 1 second sleep prior to the delete.  This seems to have slowed down the issue, but still getting more instances of this than we did on the old server.

Comment: Check the indexing service isn't running on that directory. Other than that I'm afraid procmon is probably the easiest way. CreateFile is used to open a file so you can filter on the events but it can look a little overwhelming initially.